# How to activate the dropdown menu with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add a drop-down menu to my nav-bar with bootstrap, in the context of a Flask Web App. The nav-bar and drop-down button appear, but when I click on the arrow, nothing happens. Could anyone tell me what is wrong in the code (and why)?

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Sversus</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"> 
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('add_s') }}">Add</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('list_s') }}">List</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('del_s') }}">Delete</a>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('add_s') }}">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </nav>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added the container class to have all my pages centered as you can see. If this is a bad idea, I'm interested in any alternative solution)

[image]

Comment: You need add bootstrap/jquery js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add to template the following JS libraries:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/